# User lost ability to connect from remote app server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

Server version: 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

I had an issue where a user lost the ability to connect to the mysql server from a remote application server.

- user is created as 'user'@'%'
- user has all privileges on the db in question
- user connects remotely from a cron job and runs a daily report, connectivity just seems to have disappeared

> failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'host' (using password: YES)

After confirming I could connect locally and remotely from a different server - on a whim, I issued flush privileges; this immediately resolved the problem.

I am trying to understand why - what event would have caused the lost connectivity? Really just trying to be able to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved - ended up being a network issue that was contributing to intermittent connectivity issues - flush privileges, while appearing to resolve the problem actually was not part of the issue at all.

Thanks to everybody that took a look.